# Force all dimensions to process (process update )before measure groups processing

Tags: ssas, olap-cube

while processing cube (process full), many times i get an error :

Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The attribute key cannot be found when processing: Table: 'dbo_XXX', Column: 'YYY', Value: 'abc'. The attribute is 'mmm'.
Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The record was skipped because the attribute key was not found. Attribute: Pkey of Dimension: ZZZZ from Database: aaa, Cube: bbb, Measure Group: ccc, Partition: ddd, Record: yyyy.

Even though the record is present in dim table, i get this error as my dimension record is not got processed before measure group record.

Is there a way to ensure that all dims are processed (process update) before measure group processing? 
(i use sql server enterprise edition n proactive cacheing also (polling method))

Comment: How do you process your cube? A SQL Agent Job? An Integrated Services task (SSIS)? An Xmla script?

Comment: i use proactive caching feature of enterprise edition with polling update.  so whenever there is some change in data, cube gets processed automatically.

Comment: Do you have the same silence intervals for both your dimensions and measure groups?

Comment: yes.. silence interval and silence override interval same for dimension and measure group.

Comment: Do you have polling queries for both the dimension table causing the problem and the Fact table? If so could you post details. Thanks.

Comment: whenever my ssas source db data (be it dim or fact) gets updated, i update one table and i poll that table and not dim or fact separately..